# When the player hits spikes in my game on Godot, it says my player hit multiple at the same time. I only want to hit one at a time. How do I fix this?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I am trying to make it so when the player dies in a level, all the coins they picked up in that level reset to 0, and the total coins from other levels remain the same. My problem is that whenever my player hits a patch of spikes, they often hit two at the same time, which causes double the amount of the current coins in the level to subtract.

This is the code for my spikes:

```
extends Area2D

signal kill

func _on_spike_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == "Player":
        emit_signal("kill")
```

Whenever the player hits a spike, the spike emits a signal called "kill", which is sent to the main game script.

This is my main game code:

```
func _on_spike_kill():
    Global.coins = Global.coins - current_coins
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

When the main game script receives the signal, the total coins collected are subtracted by the coins picked up in the current level, and then the scene is reset. For instance, if 5 coins are collected in the level, 5 coins would be subtracted from the total coins if the player hits the spikes. However, if the player hits two spikes at the same time, 10 coins are subtracted from the total coins.

Can someone help me?

I tried making the hit boxes of the spikes smaller, so the player couldn't hit two at the same time, but that did not work. The same thing continued to happen.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas here, but the simplest may be to set a flag that indicates if the player is currently alive or dead, and only process `_on_spike_kill()` when they are dead.  This will also prevent the reload function from being called multiple times.

```
func _on_spike_kill():
    if Global.player_active:
        Global.player_active = false
        Global.coins = Global.coins - current_coins
        get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

Then at the end of reload_current_scene(), or the start of the main loop  when the player gets control back, set `Global.player_active = true`.
This can also be used to prevent problems like user inputs moving the character when the scene is still loading, etc.

*Edit: switched order of updating player_active and coins to try to avoid a race condition.  It would be even better if player_active could be set to False within the conditional check itself*

Comment: A side note - I  don't have a lot of Godot experience so if I have a major error here, anyone can feel free to edit or correct me.  Some searches indicated Godot doesn't have a global namespace at all, but that could be out of date info as it may be version dependent, or able to be worked around with some trickery which I assume OP already did here for Global.coins.

Comment: Here `Global` must be an [Autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html).